# Is it possible to seal a leak that's coming through a fitting?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I've got a brass valve in my plumbing system that has a leak coming through the valve body wall.  I can watch tiny droplets of water diffusing through the metal itself.  I'm positive the connections on the fitting are good, and that they do not leak.  My guess is that the casting process went wrong somehow.  Short of replacing the valve, which would be a pain but would be possible, is there any way to seal this leak?

Comment: There are metal filled epoxies that may be able to seal the leak if the pressure can be turned off until it cures. These are a temporary fix , but can last for months or years if applied to cleaned dry metal until cured. I would try JB weld but start preparing to replace the valve before it fails and sprays water, causing damage to your home

Answer (score 2):

While you might be able to find an epoxy our something else out on the market your best option is replace the valve. If it was a failure in the casting process then you'll never be sure that another part of the valve won't fail. While it might be a pain it would be better to just replace it and have the peace of mind that you shouldn't have any future issues.